# Relative links using php for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

How do you link to relative links in wordpress?

For example I'm building a site onthisdomain.co.uk but the site will actually be sent live tothisdifferentdomain.co.uk.

Using the a tag brings in the full URL which I don't want as it'll cause problems when I move the sites over.  Is there a php snippet I can use? I've googled it and found an image one, `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/... " alt="" />`, but could do with an anchor one

Many thanks

Comment: <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/... " alt="" /> is what I meant to add in above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use:

"> to link directly to a page ID.

to link to your theme root

to link to the root

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for my bad English. I hope you will understand it.

I think you are a beginner in WordPress theme development. Best of luck to you. I think you know how to use CSS. What I mean, when we use `background-image` to our class. we have to think where is the image is and where is my css file is. That's how we link images to css class. If I am right. Just like that in `WordPress PHP` we can use.

So, we can use css files in any website or any domain name. if we use like see below.

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
>css->style.css
>js
>img->hello.jpg
index.php
```

Just imagin. If we use css class to `hello.jpg`

```
.myimg {
   background-image: url('css/hello.jpg');
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

So now we can use this class in any domain. But that folder structure need to be same. If I am right. Simply use, `get_template_directory_uri()`. To more info read reference.

[CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

[Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Contact me by searching `yeshansachithak` in any social network. Thanks

Comment: Is this useful for you?? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The relative links are returned from the get_template_directory_uri() function.

It probably returns a string that looks like this : "/path/to/file.jpg"

I have no experience in wordpress but making relative links isn't specifically a php thing.